# почемну ajax работает не правильно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

проблема тут в том что ответ от сервера будет `true` в типе string но if не работает что не так ?

```
$.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: '../site.php',
      data: 'status=logs&userse='+log+'&passwords='+passwords.val()+"&loginse="+loginse.val() ,
      success: function(status_login){
        console.log(status_login); // тут true
          if(status_login == "true") // но if не срабативает 
          {
            console.log(1);
            $(".button_text_user").text(login.val());
          }else{
            console.log(2);
          }
      }});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105451/discussion-on-question-by-hy-nubi--ajax---).

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '../site.php',
  data: {
    status: "logs",
    userse: log,
    passwords: passwords.val(),
    loginse: loginse.val(),
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (status_login) {
    if (status_login === true) {
      console.log(1);
      $(".button_text_user").text(login.val());
    } else {
      console.log(2);
    }
  }
});
```